# how to write routes in a laravel + vuejs 2 + vue-router + vue-axios project?

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.3, axios, vue-router, vuex

this is how i've set the files in

> /ressources/assets/js/

file:

1. /js/router/index.js & /js/router/mainRoutes.js, i wish to put my routes in mainRoutes.js
2. /js/store/index.js for state management (this is how i code in a solely vuejs project)
3. my app.js file: const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
   components:{Myheader,Myfooter}
   });

My problem is that i don't know how to set routes in this mix of languages.

Comment: this is the main route in routes.php: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('reparateursApp');
});